# Teamed network cards on a Proliant Server

Tags: networking, exchange-2010, hp, hp-proliant, nic

We have 4 network cards in a Proliant server with Server 2008R2 running Exchange 2010, with 1 card set to a static IP address and the other 3 set to DHCP.

I just need some clarification as I have not teamed network cards.

1. Do all the network cards need to have a static IP when I set as a team.
2. The connection that has the static IP is the IP that I need to use for the Server. Is it possible to set the teamed cards to the same static IP or do I have to change the static IP to another IP then use it for the teamed IP?

I will be using HP Network Configuration Utility to set this up.

Comment: Do you need teamed network interfaces?

Comment: Yes we have Exchange 2010 running on the Server and there was an issue with the Server having 4 IP addresses and our ISP which is corrected now, but it will be better moving forward to have one IP address allocated to the Server.

Comment: Teaming the NIC's because you need to have one ip address isn't a valid reason for teaming the NIC's. Just because the server has 4 NIC's doesn't mean that you have to use all 4.

Comment: I was also thinking this would help with load balancing as we have a lot of email traffic, and redundancy in case one of the NIC's die.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matt,

When you team the two NICs together the utility will create a new "Teamed" NIC in Windows that you then apply your static IP address to, rather than applying it to both NICs. Once you have created the Team the IPs on the individual NIC are are not used and the Team's IP is used instead.